# Alternating Table Rows With Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html, row, tablerow

I have the following script working to add odd and even classes to alternating table rows which works fine.

```
function alternate(){ 
if(document.getElementsByTagName){  
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
  //manipulate rows   
      if(i % 2 == 0){  
        rows[i].className = "even"; 
      }else{  
        rows[i].className = "odd"; 
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

However a problem arises when there is more than one table on a page.  I need the counter to reset for each table on the page so the first row of each table always has the same class (i.e. odd).  Currently the second table on the page will just carry on counting rows odd-even so it will start on a different class if the first table has an odd number of rows.

Can anyone help me change this code to achieve this?

Comment: Nothing to do with your script, but it seems that you want to apply a different class to even rows and to odd rows. There are CSS3 rules for that: `tr:nth-child(even)` and `tr:nth-child(odd)`.

Comment: You may want to switch the class names - the first row has an index of `0` which means that odd rows have even indexes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function alternate() {
    var i, j, tables, rows;

    tables = document.getElementsByTagName( 'table' );

    for ( i = 0; i < tables.length; i += 1 ) {
        rows = tables[i].rows;

        for ( j = 0; j < rows.length; j += 1 ) {
            rows[j].className = j % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd';
        }
    }   
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/w6rvd/

---

Alternative solution:

(Substituting the `for` iteration statements with `forEach` invocations makes the code more terse. Doesn't work in IE8 though `:/`.)

```
function alternate() {
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName( 'table' );

    [].forEach.call( tables, function ( table ) {
        [].forEach.call( table.rows, function ( row, i ) {
            row.className = i % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd';
        });
    }); 
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/w6rvd/1/

Comment: "odd" and "even" are back-to-front - the odd rows will get the even class and vice versa.

Comment: @RobG Yes, I already addressed that in a comment to the original question.

Comment: Ok, a statement to that effect in the answer would make it stand alone to help skimmers like me though. :-)

Comment: Perfect, Thanks :) Seems so obvious now!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a `for` for each table:

```
function alternate(){ 
  if(document.getElementsByTagName){  
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    // each table
    for(a = 0; a < table.length; a++){
      var rows = table[a].getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        //manipulate rows   
        if(i % 2 == 0){  
          rows[i].className = "even"; 
        }else{  
          rows[i].className = "odd"; 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this work, based on each table

```
 function alternate(){ 
 if(document.getElementsByTagName){  
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");

var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for(var a = 0; a < table.length; a++){
{
   for(var i = 0; i < table[a].rows.length; i++){
  //manipulate rows   
  if(i % 2 == 0){  
    table[a].rows[i].className = "even"; 
     }else{  
     table[a].rows[i].className = "odd"; 
      }
    }

    }

  } }

}
```